# adb shell <command> does not print to stdout

Tags: android, shell, adb

Dead simple question. My program runs for 12s, and then prints to stdout. When starting it with `adb shell` command, it does not even start...

```
$ adb shell
# /data/myprogram
CPU time: 12682.4 ms

$ adb shell /data/myprogram
<nothing>
$
```

My program runs for 12s, the log is a std::cout C++ print in stdout. I use adb-v1.0.32. My dev board runs android-5.0.2, with root access. When trying to execute it with `adb shell`, it returns to the prompt quickly. I checked if the program ran in background with `busybox ps`, it does not.

What am i missing?

Comment: Could you please provide little more details? Is <myprogram> an app that you want to launch on the emulator/ device? If so, you can "adb shell am..."

Comment: Does your program print to stdout or stderr? Please print full working and non working commands in verbatim

Comment: @AshishJadhav it is an ARM binary executable from C++ code.It prints to stdout

Comment: @m-ric It should work like that, I suggest try with a simple program _only_ printing to stdout. If that works you can continue searching the problem. Some things are different. For example environment variables.